# Custom Webview renderer in Xamarin for Windows RT not working

Tags: webview, xamarin.ios, windows-store-apps, xamarin.forms

I'm writing Webview renderer in Xamarin for Windows Desktop project by following guide in Xamarin [HybridWebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/hybridwebview/)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(ProApp.Windows.Helpers.CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace ProApp.Windows.Helpers
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.WebView, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView>
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    { //Debug Point
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (this.Control == null)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've similarly defined WebView Renderer in Android also. I'm running a Xamarin.Form Content page with WebView. The android WebView renderer is getting executed/debug but I'm not getting any debugger for Windows and code in Xamarin.Forms is running.

I also tried to add `var t = new Windows.Helpers.CustomWebViewRenderer();` in App.xaml.cs to avoid any non-inclusion after build (to have some reference to class), but didn't work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: If you pop your solution over @Vishnu I will take a quick look for you?  My contact details are on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do it is to let the XF framework implement its webview code. Inherit from WebViewRenderer instead.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Mobile.WinRT.Renderers
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer: WebViewRenderer
    {


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Also I recommend just creating a simple control in your XF project called something like CustomWebView that just inherits from WebView. Then you can render for this instead of every possible WebView in the app.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this code, but I got an error https://postimg.org/image/6quya39px/